# Why "Allgemeinen" and not "allgemein"?

Tags: grammatical-case, noun, pronoun

Why is the following sentence correct?

> Im Allgemeinen bin ich mit meiner Arbeit sehr zufrieden.

and the following wrong?

> In allgemein bin ich mit meiner Arbeit sehr zufrieden.

Why "Allgemeinen" and not "allgemein"?

Comment: Why do you believe the second sentence could be correct? What is your reasoning?

Comment: When I translate "general" on the deepl website translator, I get "allgemein" or "Allgemeines"; not "Allgemeinen". Since "general" is translated as "allgemein", I think that the second sentence should be correct. By the way, if they wanted to go for the noun, why use "Allgemeinen" instead of "Allgemeines"?
https://www.deepl.com/translator

Comment: "im Allgemeinen" translates to "in general". "the general" (noun, meaning the opposite of specific) translates to "das Allgemeine". "general" (adjective) translates to "allgemein". Are you familar with German grammar? What case is "im Allgemeinen"?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more appropriate to why English has this strange "in general" expression where a preposition is followed by an adjective.

Comment: @Roland, "im Allgemeinen" is dative. But why does the translator translate "general" as "Allgemeines"? What case is "Allgemeines"?

Comment: "Allgemeines" is nominative and (like "das Allgemeine") a nominalisation of the adjective "allgemein".

Comment: @Quant007 You cannot expect a simple literal translation from English to German to work. The result must make sense in German. *In allgemein* does not make any sense at all in German. A preposition followed by an adjective - what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you all for taking the time out to answer. I've upvoted all your comments.

Comment: @Roland: Could you combine all your comments into one answer?

Answer (score 1):

Notice the presence of the definite article *dem* (hidden in *im*). So, *im Allgemeinen* is not a direct translation of *in general*, because there is no article in *in general*. (If there was one, it would rather be *in the general* in English, but this is not proper English, of course.) Other constructions which are analogue are:

- *in the grand scheme of things* <> *im Großen und Ganzen*
- *in the month of may* <> *im Monat Mai*
- *im Besonderen* ("especially")

To me, as a German native speaker speaking English as a second language only, it looks more like *in general* is the exception here, as it is omitting the definite article being common in other analogue constructions.

The definite article forces uppercase then, because *Allgemeinen* is a substantivized noun. For some rules have a look [at the relevant section in Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Substantivierungen-von-Adjektiven).